# How to move the cursor position in a JTextField

Tags: java, cursor, jtextfield

I have a `JTextField inputTextField` and I would like the symbol `∨` to be added to the text field at the cursor position when the `orButton` is pressed. The method below works but after the button is pressed the cursor appears at the end of the field instead of at the position it was before the button is pressed.

How can I set the cursor to move back to its previous position?

```
private void orButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                          
    {
        int caretPosition = inputTextField.getCaretPosition();
        String currentText = inputTextField.getText();
        String newText = currentText.substring(0, caretPosition) + 
        "∨" + currentText.substring(caretPosition, currentText.length());

        inputTextField.setText(newText);
        inputTextField.requestFocus();
    }
```

I thought `setCaretPosition()` might be what I was looking for but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setCaretPosition()` should be the right method. However it seems the caret is set to position `0` again when the text field gets the focus. You could try wrapping it inside a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` call like this:

```
private void orButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt) {
    final int caretPosition = inputTextField.getCaretPosition();
    String currentText = inputTextField.getText();
    String newText = currentText.substring(0, caretPosition) + 
    "∨" + currentText.substring(caretPosition, currentText.length());

    inputTextField.setText(newText);
    inputTextField.requestFocus();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            inputTextField.setCaretPosition(caretPosition);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that you have to declare `caretPosition` as final for this to work.

Comment: PS: There might be a more elegant solution using lambdas, but we are still stuck at Java 7, and I don't know what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

setCaretPosition works as expected. You need to call this before or after calling requestFocus method. The working example is provided below:

```
private void orButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                          
{
    int caretPosition = inputTextField.getCaretPosition();
    String currentText = inputTextField.getText();
    String newText = currentText.substring(0, caretPosition) + 
    "∨" + currentText.substring(caretPosition, currentText.length());

    inputTextField.setText(newText);
    inputTextField.requestFocus();
    inputTextField.setCaretPosition(caretPosition);
}
```

Comment: I've tried it with setCaretPosition in various positions including your suggested position and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

what resets the position of the caret is the `setText()`, not the field getting the focus. If you put the `setCaretPosition()` between `setText()` and `requestFocus()` it should work.

This is a working example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    JButton b = new JButton("button");
    tf.setText("abcdefghijklmnop");
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
           int caretPosition = tf.getCaretPosition();
            String currentText = tf.getText();
            String left = currentText.substring(0, caretPosition);
            String right = currentText.substring(caretPosition, currentText.length());
            String newText = left + "v" + right;
            tf.setText(newText);
            tf.setCaretPosition(caretPosition+1);
            tf.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    JPanel p = (JPanel)f.getContentPane();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);
    p.add(tf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.setSize(640, 400);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely  right that `setText` resets the caret position, but since OP already said that he had tried, I guess it must be happening when the focus changes. I have seen things like that several times (works on my linux computer at home but doesn't on windows in office or vice versa) that I suspect it might also be dependent on the look and feel that is being used.

Comment: notnek, can you provide details of your configuration: which OS, and which java version?

Comment: Java 8 on Windows 8.1